# how to select tables to upload to Mysql from a form

Tags: php, mysql

PHP beginner here & I would like to ask a question about using forms to upload info to a database. 
I have a website with 48 different categories. www.ralphslocal.com . If you visit the site you will see that for each category I am pulling info from separate tables off of my database.

The form im using to populate the tables is missing a way to select the table I want to upload to. At this point, when I want to upload to a different table I need to change the table name in "insert.php"

What do i need to be able to select the table I want to upload to on the form? 
If im unclear I apologize. I appreciate any help you can give.

Here is the code for my form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
<p>Retailer:&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;<input type="text" name="retailer"></p>
<p>WebSite:&#160;&#160;&#160;<input type="text" name="website"></p>
<p>City:&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;<select name="city">
                       <option value="BellaVista">BellaVista</option>
                       <option value="Bentonville">Bentonville</option>
                       <option value="Centerton">Centerton</option>
                       <option value="Farmington">Farmington</option>
                       <option value="Fayetteville">Fayetteville</option>
                       <option value="Lowell">Lowell</option>
                       <option value="Rogers">Rogers</option>
                       <option value="Springdale">Springdale</option>
                       <option value="Tontitown">Tontitown</option>
                       <option value="West Fork">West Fork</option>
                                                           </select></p>
<p>Phone:&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;<input type="text" name="phone"></p>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the code for my "insert.php" file:

```
<?php require 'connect.php'; ?>

<?php
$sql="INSERT INTO garden_nursery (Retailer, WebSite, City, Phone)
VALUES
('$_POST[retailer]','$_POST[website]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[phone]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}{
echo "1 record added";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks So Much!
Ralph

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Comment: How do you determine which table to update?

Comment: Thanks for the links & the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple. Add this to your form:

```
 <select name='data_table'>
  <option value='appliances'> Appliances </option>
  <option value='garden_nursery'> Garden Nursery </option>
  <option value='table_name_formated'> Table Name </option> 
  <!-- and so on for all of youre tables -->
 </select>
```

In insert.php change the line where you assing value to $sql to this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $_POST[data_table] (Retailer, WebSite, City, Phone) 
VALUES ('$_POST[retailer]','$_POST[website]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[phone]')";
```

Additional notes: 
After visiting your site, if I can see it correctly, you made 38 different tables, with the same data structure. Why didn't you just add one more column to a single "alldata"(or something simmilar) named table, which stores the respective category? This way when you add new categories later, you don't need to make new tables all the time.

Additional notes 2:
It would also be safer to escape the user provided input, before you try to store it in the database, like tadman said. Add this to your insert.php file, in the place where you assing value to $sql.

```
$datatable=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['data_table']);
$retailer=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['retailer']);
$website=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['website']);
$city=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
$phone=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);
$sql="INSERT INTO $datatable (Retailer, WebSite, City, Phone) VALUES ('$retailer','$website','$city','$phone')";
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks very much for leading me in the right direction on this. Its a big help.